# htaccess rewrites for two directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to use rewrite rules for accessing two directories. I grabbed and tested a lot of code from online and other SO posts but what I ended up with still doesn't work properly. Here's what I'm trying to do:

1) If page request is for /home, /test, /404, /etc, load the files from the /app directory and traverse like this: /home, /news/topics/post, /contact/, /blog/category/date/post

2) If the page request is for /admin only, then load the files from the /admin directory and be able to traverse like so: /admin or /dashboard, /admin/page/edit, /admin/page/delete, /admin/page/create, /admin/section/delete/

What is happening?
If I go to /home or just /, works just fine! But if I got to /test, /contact, /admin, /etc I get a 404 file not found

File structure (can be changed though):

```
/admin
 --dashboard.php

/app
 --index.php

.favicon.png
.favicon.ico
.htaccess
```

I'm starting to think that it might be better to just hard-code the rewrites like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^home$ /atlas.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin$ /admin/dashboard.php [NC,L]
```

...but I thought I'd see if the SO community could help before I throw in the towel on this one.

Any suggestions?

My current code:

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks


# Set the default site page
DirectoryIndex /app/index.php home


# Rewrite Rules and Conditions
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NC]


# Assets are in /app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|svg|swf)$ /app/$1.$2 [L,NC]


# First, check if request is to site pages, which is in /app/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php?/$1 [NC,L]


# Second, check if request is to /admin, which is in /admin/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/dashboard.php?/$1 [NC,L]


# Default to /app
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/app/
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /app/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just do:

```
#admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/admin(.*)$ /admin_handler.php?path=$1 [QSA]

#app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /app_handler.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

If all your URLs need `/app` in them why not just put `/app` in them? Adding it in the rewrite is pointless.

When you have rewrites it's great to have a *single point of entry* because you just rewrite everything to that file and let PHP handle it. It's much easier to figure out what a request is in PHP than in `mod_rewrite`. This setup now has two entry points, one for visitors and one for the admin stuff but you can even just merge those into one.

Comment: I don't use this method:

    ?path=$1&$2&$3

Comment: There is no `$2` and `$3`, `$1` already matches everything. Your malformed query strings are a little peculiar, I would not recommend that.

Comment: I keep admin files separate from the site or app because there may be multiple apps. I don't like mixing admin code that may be messed with by devs working on app stuff only

Comment: Ah, well that would attribute to what I've found on SO so far. The htaccess is a mix of what I've found that worked for others. So perhaps I need to rewrite the entire thing?

Comment: That is my advice. A lot of solutions you'll see are for applications that just need a little bit of rewriting here and there. If you're going to rewrite all your URLs anyway better just make a _single point of entry_ and do away with all the gimmicks.

Comment: I hear what you're saying but I don't want the /admin/ directory inside of /app/. I want to keep the file structure as posted above. How would I handle the rewrites in that case?

Comment: All the URLs are rewritten so `admin` and `app` may not even exist on the filesystem. It's entirely up to you where you put your code.

Comment: I'll accept your code but I ended up rewriting it so there is one index.php file and everything pivots through there. Thank you for the assistance and suggestion to keep it DRY and KISS.